# Как сделать проверку спецификации в django?

Tags: python, django, спецификация

Есть три модели:

1. описание образца (Sample)
2. показатель (value) который определяется для этого образца (Protein)
3. спецификация в которой нормируется данный показатель (protein_value) у клиента (Specification).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, есть ли возможность сделать проверку на предмет совпадения со спецификацией?
Причина, по которой я вынес её в отдельную модель та, что клиентов у нас три и у каждого свое отличное значение protein_min. И я хотел бы сделать так, чтобы при проверке: `if value > protein_min` в шаблон прилетело {{ name }} клиента.